# Как увеличить размер стека для пользователя jar архива?

Tags: java, jvm

Как увеличить размер стека для своей jvm я знаю (Запускаю у себя через idea с флагом -Xss64M), но вот как сделать, что бы у пользователя моего JAR был увеличенный стек?

Ответ типа «пусть пользователь увеличит стек сам» — не подходит.

Общее описание задачи:
Есть алгоритм, который рекурсивно обходит двумерный массив и ищет возможные области, в которых есть различные пиксели, дел в том, что если различий много, стандартного стека не хватает.

Comment: Задать настройки JVM по-умолчанию для конкретного JAR нельзя (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018217/can-i-set-java-max-heap-size-for-running-from-a-jar-file). Все используют обходные манёвры: подсовывают пользователю скрипт либо обертку, которые запускают JVM с нужными аргументами. Попробуйте описать подробнее что у Вас за приложение и как оно запускается, может кто-нибудь предложит альтернативу.

Comment: Есть алгоритм, который рекурсивно обходит двумерный массив и ищет возможные области, в которых есть различные пиксели, дел в том, что если различий много, стандартного стека не хватает. Про скрипт либо обертку можно подробней?

Comment: Как это все запускаете Вы? Как устанавливаете размер стека? Как будет запускать пользователь (критично ли это)?

Comment: Запускаю у себя через idea с флагом -Xss64M, пользователь будет запускать через jar'ик, достаточно критично, так-как даже 20% не соответствий при размерах 800х600 уже не влезают в стандартный стек)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Размер выделенной памяти устанавливается на уровне JVM и не может быть задан для конкретного JAR файла.

Соответственно, задача сводится к тому чтобы запустить виртуальную машину с заданными параметрами. Для этого JAR запускается пользователем не напрямую, а через промежуточное звено, это может быть:

- Скрипт для запуска, как правило, специфичный для ОС. Например на Windows, можно дать пользователю файл run.bat, который запустит JAR с заданными настройками:

  ```
    java -Xss64M -jar MyRunnable.jar
  ```
- Обертка — специально созданное для этой цели приложение (JAR, либо другой исполняемый файл), который запустит Java с заданными параметрами. Есть средства, которые генерируют обертку автоматически (например, [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) опять-таки для Windows)

Похожий вопрос на английском про размер кучи: [Can I set Java max heap size for running from a jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018217/can-i-set-java-max-heap-size-for-running-from-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тут](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/166?locale=ru) описано такое решение:
"Правильно запускать новый Thread с нужным размером стека и в нем осуществлять решение задачи"

```
new Thread(null, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Main().run();
        }
    }, "1", 1 << 23).start();
```

Для потока "1" будет установлен размер стека в 8Mb.